# Why is nmap now taking a long time to perform subnet ping?

Tags: nmap

I've been using the nmap tool on my Windows machine to ping my Uni house home network range using the following command:

```
nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -sn
```

I had no problems with this and it was only taking 5-10 seconds to complete. Since I've returned home for Easter (different home/network) I've tried to use the command again (albeit this time with a different subnet address

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sn
```

and it is taking around 50 seconds+ to do the same.

I just checked a simple nmap 192.168.0.1 -sn and that is taking around 12 seconds...

Does anyone know why this could be? Some bad network setup or something? I'm pretty baffled at the moment but maybe i've missed something simple..

Comment: As a new user, you should read the FAQ. Questions pertaining to home users and home networks, particularly for enthusiasts, should be posted to SuperUser, not ServerFault. SF is meant for people who work in IT professionally. This question will be migrated automatically when it's gathered enough close-votes.

Comment: Do you administer this network ?

Comment: Yeah, they are both my home networks (& apologies for posting on wrong site)

Answer (score 2):

`nmap` tries to scan your network for live IPs addresses and ports. If there are more live IPs in your subnet, `nmap` will finish sooner. This is because it is faster to say there is a live host with IP `192.168.1.1` than to say there is no live host with the IP `192.168.1.1`.

So, it should be normal to get different times for different subnets.